# ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server

Tags: ldap, bind

I have below code and I am getting error:

Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in C:\xampp\htdocs\ldap.php on line 17

```
<?php
$ldapconfig['host'] = "dsua1.company.com";
$ldapconfig['port'] = 636;
$ldapconfig['basedn'] = "cn=userid,ou=Applications,ou=Company,ou=Services,dc=iM-2,dc=com";
$ldapconfig['binddn'] = "userid";
$ldapconfig['bindpw'] = "password";
$ldapconn=ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'],$ldapconfig['port']);

ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapconfig['binddn'], $ldapconfig['bindpw']);
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you specified port 636, I assume that you need an SSL-connection to the server. This is achieved by:

```
ldap_connect("ldaps://".$ldapconfig['host']."/");
```

Otherwise it would try to send plaintext data which would not be accepted on an SSL-socket.

Furthermore, try this after ldap_connect() and before ldap_bind():

```
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
```

Sometimes an error occurs when an incorrect protocol version is used, 3 is common now, but not standard for the ldap_* PHP function family.

Comment: I added what you said but still same error. Connection to LDAP is good but Looks like DN string is not correct in ldap_bin

Comment: @LordOfTheRing Ok, added another suggestion. Still the same error or did the message change?

Comment: same error "Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in C:\xamp\htdocs\ldap.php" even after adding ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3); as per your suggestion.

Comment: Then please doublecheck that the server is running and reachable from the client host running the php script i.e. by `telnet ldaphost 636` and seeing if a connect succeeds

Comment: Below statement shows successful so I am able to connect but seems binding some parameter is not passed correctly and not sure which one is wrong. if($ldapconn) echo "New LDAP session successful";

Comment: @LordOfTheRing ldap_connect does not really connect, but just stores the connection parameters. The connection is initiated with the ldap_bind call

Comment: You will need to pass the port in the url. So you might want to try ldap_connect('ldaps://'.$ldapconcig['host'].':636'); instead.   When using the URI-Scheme the second parameter is not used at all. As a matter of fact this second parameter is not to be used at all. It's just there to support old codebases.

Comment: @heiglandreas When ldaps:// is used as urlscheme port 636 is used by default

Comment: I tried ldap_connect('ldaps://'.$ldapconcig['host'].':636'); but same error

Comment: Did you try to telnet yet?

Comment: @LordOfTheRing: You're absolutely right: When no port is provided the default one for ldaps is used.

Comment: @Ctx: Does your LDAP-Server use some special certificates? Is the LDAP-Server reachable from your Webserver? If the LDAP-Server is behind a firewall you might not be able to get through at all without altering that firewall.

Comment: @heiglandreas Mine does work quite well, thanks for asking ;)